# spark structured streaming operation duration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a structured streaming job with kafka source.
spark: 2.4.7
python: 3.6.8

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

ds = (spark.readStream
           .format("kafka")
           .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_servers)
           .option("subscribe", topic_name)
           .load())

# data preprocessing
ds = ...

model = GBTClassificationModel.load(model_path)

ds = model.transform(ds)  

query = (ds.writeStream
           .outputMode("update")
           .format("kafka")
           .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_servers)
           .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_dir)
           .option("topic", output_topic)
           .trigger(processingTime="0 seconds")
           .start())

query.awaitTermination()
```

The spark web UI displays the following indicators:

`AddBatch`: 1955.0
`GetBatch`: 1.0
`GetOffset`: 0.0
`QueryPlanning`: 3555.0
`TriggerExecution`: 2.0
`WalCommit`: 5569.0
`undefined`: 20.0

The following is a description of the indicators on the [spark official website](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/web-ui.html#structured-streaming-tab):

Operation Duration. The amount of time taken to perform various operations in milliseconds. The tracked operations are listed as follows.

1. `addBatch`: Time taken to read the micro-batch’s input data from the sources, process it, and write the batch’s output to the sink. ***This should take the bulk of the micro-batch’s time***.
2. `getBatch`: Time taken to prepare the logical query to read the input of the current micro-batch from the sources.
3. `latestOffset & getOffset`: Time taken to query the maximum available offset for this source.
4. `queryPlanning`: Time taken to generates the execution plan.
5. `walCommit`: Time taken to write the offsets to the metadata log.

***Why are `WalCommit` and `QueryPlanning` much larger than `AddBatch`?***

Thanks！

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67118601/spark-structured-streaming-join-stream-static-joins